# Google Sheet How to Keep Notes on New Column on a Dynamic Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with the following sheets:

**ordenes**: this sheet gets the raw orders from an ecommerce without any kind of filters.

**pendientesdepago**: this sheet uses a QUERY function to filter all the "pending payment" orders.

I want to be able to write notes on "pendingpayments" sheet right next to each record, on a new column.

The problem this sheet is dynamic and updates frequently. For example when new orders come in on "raworders" sheet some rows on "pendingpayments" might disappear or change the order so i cant keep the notes "locked" to the original raw.

I know the definitive solution would be not to use Google Sheet and use a CRM but that's not possible on this implementation.

Any idea what could I do?

UPDATE:
Test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rU_lGGN9iW9vX2vRZSYqNX4FmwM41lB-h9Wx-n_5Qx4/edit?usp=sharing

A simple column containing checkboxes will do it. If its checked it will indicate the contact was contacted and if its not it would mean it needs to be contacted because it wasnt contacted yet.

IF I add a fixed column right next to the orders when the QUERY function beings new orders the new column containing the checkbox will not match the orderids.

Comment: Can you tie notes to order numbers and keep them on a notes page?

Comment: How would u do that

Comment: I not sure without looking at the spreadsheet in more detail but lets say that you have a list of orders with their order numbers you can click on a row and then click on a menu item or a button that's on a sidebar and have an editable note appear on a dialog or sidebar by looking up the note with the order number.

Comment: It's like most databases keep different things on different tables and they join them together depending upon the needs of a given situation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a unique identifier for each row, say Order Number which may be 1st column of your pendingpayments sheet, then you can create a new sheet say "NotesSheet" which has two columns (OrderNumber, Notes). 
Now you can make use of VLookup formula in your pendingpayments sheet to look for matching Order Number and fetch the notes corresponding to that Order , something like

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,NotesSheet!$A:$B,2, false)
```

so even if the rows gets deleted or Order Number row moves up or down, it will still be able to fetch the notes corresponding to that Order.

Comment: The problem is people will be taking notes on pendingorders sheets because they will.be looking at the contact info from those orders directly. They can't be taking notes on a separate sheet where they only see orderids

Comment: They can if they can set their cursor on an order number and click a menu that pulls up the notes for that order number in a dialog.  They can edit the dialog and save the note.

Comment: @Cooper how would u do the dialog to write notes all within pendingpayment sheet

Comment: @Cooper is it even possible to add a column to pendingpayments sheet for "notes" and then somewhat lock the notes to the orderid so if it loses order notes would stick next to the corresponding record? the solution using an addon or menu with popup dialog seems complicated

Comment: I don't have to convince you of anything if you don't believe it can work that's fine with me.

Comment: @Cooper i understand what u propose just have no clue how to implement

Comment: Well given that I've never even seen you spreadsheet and I don't know anything about it, I'd have to agree I don't know how to do it either.  But I do believe it's possible.

Comment: @Cooper https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rU_lGGN9iW9vX2vRZSYqNX4FmwM41lB-h9Wx-n_5Qx4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I thought u waned to see an example